# updateSearchResultsForSearchController not called in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to write a simple `UITableView` with a `UISearchBar`. I have no problem when I drag and drop a `UITableViewController`. Everything works! (see code below)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.searchResultsController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil) //initialize the search controller
    self.searchResultsController.searchResultsUpdater = self //the search controller updater is this view
    self.searchResultsController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchResultsController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.searchResultsController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
    self.searchResultsController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchResultsController.searchBar
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But now, for experimental purpose, I used `UIViewController`, and added a `UITableView`, no problem with showing my records in the table.

Then, added a UISearchBar from the storyboard, set its delegate to the UIViewController, but the `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` method is not called when the user type in something.

It's like my UISearchController has no idea there is a `UISearchBar`, and what ever I type in, does not evoke the updating method. Do I have to tell the UISearchController that hey this is your `UISearchBar`?

So here's top of my code:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate
```

{

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySearchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var myViewTable: UITableView!

let allElements = ["H", "Li", "Na", "K", "Rb", "Cs", "Fr"]
var filteredElemetns = [String]()
var searchResultsController = UISearchController() //create a new search controller

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.searchResultsController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil) //initialize the search controller
    self.searchResultsController.searchResultsUpdater = self //the search controller updater is this view
    self.searchResultsController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchResultsController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.searchResultsController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
    self.searchResultsController.searchBar.delegate = self

    //self.myViewTable.tableHeaderView = self.searchResultsController.searchBar
}
```

If I uncomment the last line, then I'll have two `UISearchBar`, which one is added by the storyboard and the other one with the last line code. The one I added, does not work, but the one at top of the `myViewTable` does.

Comment: does your class conform to the UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate protocols?

Comment: missing searchController.searchBar.delegate = self?

Comment: I used the storyboard to set the delegate, but also tried it programmatically, didn't work

Comment: What kind of search bar did you use from the storyboard a normal search bar or search bar and search display controller?

Comment: Normal search bar, the second one is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution.

I used my filtering algorithm inside `searchBar:textDidChange` function. Then everything worked, and I don't need `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` function anymore. Here is my code:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    print("filtering...")
    self.filteredElemetns.removeAll(keepCapacity: false) //remove all the elements

    let searchPredict = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS [c] %@", self.mySearchBar.text!)

    print(searchPredict)

    let foundElements = (self.allElements as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredict)

    self.filteredElemetns = foundElements as! [String]

    self.myViewTable.reloadData()
}
```

Of course, don't forget to make sure your class conforms to `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol.

I find this approach better than using a `UITableViewController`. One reason, if you search, you will find that many people have a problem with making `UISearchBar` the first responder. The only solution to that, I found, is calling `becomeFirstResponder` after a delay, which is really not a good programming approach.

But, with this approach, you can make an outlet of your `UISearchBar` and then easy make it the first responder in `viewDidAppear`.

I know some people might say no you can easily make the `UISearchBar` the first responder even if you use `UISearchResultsController` by doing something like:

```
self.searchResultsController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
self.searchResultsController.active = true
```

But, believe me in iOS 8/9 it is not that simple, it won't work. Try it...

Comment: So what is the reason that updateSearchResultsForSearchController was not being called ?